# Creating a legend for a histogram graph in ggplot2 that is colored according to the data subset the histogram data came from

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I'm trying to tell ggplot to reference the two subsets of data to color my histogram bars. How do I direct the fill function in AES to color the scores based on which dataset the data came from?

```
SW_WP_data=subset(sw_og, OG_CTYPE=="WP" & DSGSTTXT=="Designated" & OG_CLASS=="Pine")
ASP_WP_data=subset(sw_og, OG_CTYPE=="WP" & DSGSTTXT=="Designated" & OG_CLASS=="Pine" & NEWSUBSC=="ASP")

SW_ASP_WP=ggplot(data=SW_WP_data, aes(x=OGSCORE), fill=?) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=.6, alpha=.6, col="black") +
  geom_histogram(data=ASP_WP_data, binwidth=.6, fill='red', col="black", alpha=.6)+
  geom_vline(xintercept=33, linetype="dashed", colour="red")+
  xlim(0,65)+
  ylim(0,15)+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5))+
  labs(title = "Statewide vs. ASP", y= "Count", x="Scores", caption = "2012 data")+
  scale_fill_discrete(name="Data Extent", values=c("grey5", "red3"), labels=c("Statewide", "ASP"))
```

The [image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDvvP.png)  shows what I'm trying to make, but with a legend that references the scores that came from two different dataframes. How do I direct the fill function in AES to color the scores based on which dataset the data came from?

Answer (score 0):

Generally ggplot expects data in long format, so you don't need to subset the dataframe like you did above; you should just assign a variable to the fill aesthetic, and thus only call `geom_histogram` once. You didn't include data, so I'm doing a mockup with the iris dataset.

**Edit** to include bringing together two datasets:

Say you want to compare the setosa irises to all species of irises. What I generally do is make my subset, add a column to flag it, and bind it back to the full dataset that also has a flag column.

```
setosa_only <- iris %>% 
    filter(Species == "setosa") %>% 
    mutate(flag = "setosa")
df <- iris %>% 
    mutate(flag = "all irises") %>%
    bind_rows(setosa_only)
```

Something like this should get what you want:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Sepal.Length, fill = flag)) +
  geom_histogram(position = "dodge") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 5, linetype = "dashed", color = "red") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey5", "red3", "steelblue"))
```

Plus whatever bells & whistles you want.

A couple things to note:

- Since I don't have your data, I don't know the significance of the x-intercept. I just threw in a dummy value.
- Since fill is being mapped to an aesthetic, it needs to go inside `aes`.
- If you want to assign colors manually, you want `scale_fill_manual`, not `scale_fill_discrete`. The `scale_*_manual` functions are the ones that have a `values` parameter to which you can assign colors, sizes, shapes, etc.
- In the edited version, I added `position = "dodge"` to the histogram. That's because you're showing a subset as it compares to the whole, so you want to be clear that you aren't adding the count of irises in one bin plus the number of setosa irises in that bin.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I subset the data into two formats because I'm comparing evaluation scores across the state and a smaller subset of the state data (one county). It's unclear how I would reference all of the state data, but then only reference one counties data without subsetting.

Comment: Okay, I'll edit my answer with an example of how I often do that

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Camille. I didn't know about this flagging function. I think this will work.